# OpenVPN works for some ISP and not on some others

Tags: openvpn, amazon-ec2

I have set up an OpenVPN access server using AWS AMI. I have a requirement that I need to whitelist an IP for some data access. So I have whitelisted an Elastic IP from AWS attached that to OpenVPN access server. So that, when I connect to the VPN, I can access the whitelisted site locally.

All the configurations are working and when I connect, it will show **Initialization sequence completed**. The problem is, it works for one Internet service provider (JIO) and when I connected to another ISP (Asianet), it was not working. How can I resolve the issue?

This is the difference in the log that I see when connecting:

This one is working (JIO):

```
Thu Jun 18 18:50:40 2020 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.43.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlp3s0 HWADDR=XXXXXXXXXXX
Thu Jun 18 18:50:40 2020 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Thu Jun 18 18:50:40 2020 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Thu Jun 18 18:50:40 2020 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Thu Jun 18 18:50:40 2020 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 192.168.40.7/24 broadcast 192.168.40.255
Thu Jun 18 18:50:45 2020 ROUTE remote_host is NOT LOCAL
Thu Jun 18 18:50:45 2020 /sbin/ip route add X.X.X.X/32 via 192.168.43.1
Thu Jun 18 18:50:45 2020 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.40.1
Thu Jun 18 18:50:45 2020 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.40.1
Thu Jun 18 18:50:45 2020 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

This is not working (Asianet):

```
Fri Jun 19 09:21:06 2020 ROUTE_GATEWAY 100.110.0.1/255.255.0.0 IFACE=enp2s0 HWADDR=XXXXXXXXXXXX
Fri Jun 19 09:21:06 2020 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Jun 19 09:21:06 2020 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Fri Jun 19 09:21:06 2020 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Fri Jun 19 09:21:06 2020 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 192.168.40.7/24 broadcast 192.168.40.255
Fri Jun 19 09:21:11 2020 ROUTE remote_host is NOT LOCAL
Fri Jun 19 09:21:11 2020 /sbin/ip route add X.X.X.X/32 via 100.110.0.1
Fri Jun 19 09:21:11 2020 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.40.1
Fri Jun 19 09:21:11 2020 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.40.1
Fri Jun 19 09:21:11 2020 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

(Note: I have replaced my VPN IP with X.X.X.X/32 here)

How can I find out the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: **What do you mean by "not working"?** Does the site see you as connecting from the wrong IP address? Or are you unable to connect to the site at all? If it's the former, what IP address _does_ the website see? (I'm already betting on it being an IPv6 address though.)

Comment: ***Not working*** means, when I curl to get IP address I'm getting this response: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipconfig.io`. Also, no other websites are loading on the browser too.

Comment: When I'm connecting to the VPN, I'm not getting any error. It says **Initialization Sequence Completed**, but no Internet after that.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this is the result of having the following:

- Your PC still tries to use whatever DNS
- You have `redirect-gateway def1` in your VPN server config

This means your PC will try to reach the DNS resolver from outside your ISP’s network (via VPN). The ISP may or may not allow that. Note that if the DNS resolver is in your local network, it will still be reachable even if connected to the VPN, because the route to your local network is more specific (longer prefix).

To work around this problem, you have multiple options:

- Use something like Google DNS, Cloudflare DNS – a public resolver on the internet

  - Either statically on your PC
  - Or using OpenVPN’s `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.66.0.4"` (requires additional scripting on non-Windows clients)
- Run your own DNS resolver (eg. DNSMASQ) on the VPN server and use OpenVPN’s `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.66.0.4"` (still only works on Windows out of the box)

In OpenVPN Access Server (a commercial web management GUI for OpenVPN), you can apparently set this in VPN Settings -> DNS Settings -> Have clients use these DNS servers.

Comment: Where do I add this `push` command? In the VPN server's config file? If yes, can you please tell me where is that file located in OpenVPN access server AMI image?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I'm not familiar with the commercial OpenVPN Access Server, so I cannot verify this information.

Answer (score 0):

If this works for one ISP but not other

Then its the ISP who is blocking the requests

It is recommend to use **VPN** for the ISP which dont works(Asianet)

Connect to VPN when you are on asianet and recheck